# KSQL Streams and Tables does not persists data

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming, ksqldb

I create one kafka topic and i created a KSQL stream on this topic and i create a table on the stream to do aggregation,
after restarting KSQL Server and Kafka, all KSQL Streams and tables gone !
is there any way to configure KSQL Server to keep the streams and tables on the desk. 
does it store the data on RAM only?

Comment: What version of Confluent Platform are you using? How are you running Confluent Platform? For example, are you using Confluent CLI? Docker, etc? 
By design, KSQL persists both metadata (stream/table definitions) as well as the created topics in Kafka itself. It sounds like somehow you're losing your Kafka topic data between restarts.

Comment: Agreed. What do you mean by "restart"? Other than Docker, `confluent start` also is not designed to hold persistent data by default

Comment: we are installing zookeeper, kafka separately not using confluent docker image, and we are using ksql separately as well we build ksql from the ksql source in git hub and it is running with ksql client on port 8088.
Does ksql server presist streams, the ksql tables store its data on kafka topic but what about the streams since no kafka topic is create for the ksql stream but for ksql tables there is kafka topic created.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in a very early version of ksqlDB that could of caused this, but it has been fixed for many versions now. Please retry with a more up to date version.